# Index words whose length more than 3 in solr

Tags: solr, tokenize

I am indexing large textual paragraphs in Solr (version 6.5).

I need to index only those words whose length is more than 3 characters (characters only). But indexing of numbers in needed. Example - 'ask' and 'as' are not needed but '10' and '101' are needed.

One way to achieve this is to take all possible combinations in stopwords.txt file.

Can someone please suggest me a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a filter in your fieldType analyzer.

There is a pattern filter which replace the matched values. You can replace them with an empty value. Something like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\b[a-z]{1,3}\b)" replacement="" replace="all" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Maybe you just need to change the pattern to meet your requirements.

**Update**: I've updated the pattern. I guess this one (\b[a-z]{1,3}\b) should do the trick. At least I've tested it [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), and it looks correct for your rule.
Basically the pattern just complain about words with a-z letters of size 1 to 3 (the ones will be ignored)

Also, I've added a LowerCaseFilter and an ASCIIFoldingFilter (which you probably already have configured) before the PatternFilter, so the pattern filter doesn't need to complain about upper case and special characters.

Here is a documentation about the filter if you need more info: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/pattern/PatternReplaceCharFilter.html

Comment: This will replace any character outside of a-z0-9, not consider the length of the words/tokens - which is what the question is about. The asker wants to remove all _tokens_ that are shorter than four characters, but not if the token is numeric. You could probably modify it by doing `^[^0-9]{1,3}$` instead - depending on use case only on indexing or both querying and indexing.

Comment: The asker wants a better way to ignore some tokens based on a specific rule, which is what I gave him. As said in the answer, he just need to adapt the pattern to meet his rule. I'm not expert in regex, but another person or himself can get that part correctly. In the meanwhile I'm looking around for it too.